# Convert .geojson to .wkt | extract 'coordinates'

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, geojson

Goal: Ultimately, to convert `.geojson` to `.wkt`. Here, I want to extract all `coordinates`, each as a list.

In [my.geojson](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/danielbellsa/90d08baa409e2abca88ca89cb329a352/raw/6e74654314b47a7b0f3777f0ff840238cd6a5176/my.geojson), there are **n** many: `{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":...`

Update: I've successfully extracted the first `coordinates`. However, this file has two `coordinates`.

---

Every `.geojson` has at least 1 `coordinates`, but may have more.

**How can I dynamically extract all key-values of many `coordinates`?**

Code:

```py
from pathlib import Path
import os
import geojson
import json
from shapely.geometry import shape


ROOT = Path('path/')

all_files = os.listdir(ROOT)
geojson_files = list(filter(lambda f: f.endswith('.geojson'), all_files))

for gjf in geojson_files:
    with open(f'{str(ROOT)}/{gjf}') as f:
        gj = geojson.load(f)
    o = dict(coordinates = gj['features'][0]['geometry']['coordinates'], type = "Polygon")
    geom = shape(o)
    wkt = geom.wkt
```

Desired Output:
1 `.wkt` for all corrdinates in geojson

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To convert a series of geometries in GeoJSON files to WKT, the shape() function can convert the GeoJSON geometry to a shapely object which then can be formatted as WKT and/or projected to a different coordinate reference system.

If want to access the coordinates of polygon once it's in a shapely object, use
`x,y = geo.exterior.xy`.

If just want to convert a series of GeoJSON files into one .wkt file per GeoJSON file then try this:

```python
from pathlib import Path
import json
from shapely.geometry import shape

ROOT = Path('path')

for f in ROOT.glob('*.geojson'):
    with open(f) as fin, open(f.with_suffix(".wkt"), "w") as fout:
        features = json.load(fin)["features"]
        for feature in features:
            geo = shape(feature["geometry"])
            # format geometry coordinates as WKT
            wkt = geo.wkt
            print(wkt)
            fout.write(wkt + "\n")
```

This output uses your example my.geojson file.

**Output:**

```
POLYGON ((19372 2373, 19322 2423, ...
POLYGON ((28108 25855, 27755 26057, ...
```

If need to convert the coordinates to EPSG:4327 (WGS-84) (e.g. 23.314208, 37.768469), you can use *pyproj*.

Full code to convert collection of GeoJSON files to a new GeoJSON file in WGS-84.

```python
from pathlib import Path
import json
import geojson
from shapely.geometry import shape, Point
from shapely.ops import transform
from pyproj import Transformer

ROOT = Path('wkt/')
features = []

# assume we're converting from 3857 to 4327
# and center point is at lon=23, lat=37

c = Point(23.676757000000002, 37.9914205)

local_azimuthal_projection = f"+proj=aeqd +R=6371000 +units=m +lat_0={c.y} +lon_0={c.x}"
aeqd_to_wgs84 = Transformer.from_proj(local_azimuthal_projection,
                                      '+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs')

for f in ROOT.glob('*.geojson'):
    with open(f) as fin:
        features = json.load(fin)["features"]
        for feature in features:
            geo = shape(feature["geometry"])
            poly_wgs84 = transform(aeqd_to_wgs84.transform, geo)
            features.append(geojson.Feature(geometry=poly_wgs84))

# Output new GeoJSON file
with open("out.geojson", "w") as fp:
    fc = geojson.FeatureCollection(features)
    fp.write(geojson.dumps(fc))
```

Assuming the conversion is from EPSG:3857 to EPSG:4327 and center point is at lon=23, lat=37, the output GeoJSON file will look like this:

```
{"features": [{"type": "Polygon", "geometry": {"coordinates": [[[23.897879, 38.012554], ...
```

Comment: Tysm. Very comprehensive and new knowledge gained here